# Prove that similar matrices have the same geometric multiplicity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I'm trying to prove in two cases where two similar matrices are diagonalizable or non-diagonalizable? If they are diagonalizable, obviously the statement holds. But what if they are not? Can non-diagonalizable matrices still be similar? If yes, show me an example please. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know Jordannormalform? You will surely love it

Comment: @user63219 About your last question: take any non diagonalizable matrix $A$. Now take (almost) any invertible matrix $P$ and consider the matrix $P^{-1}AP$. By definition $P^{-1}AP$ is similar to $A$ and they aren't diagonalizable.

Comment: @GitGud any $P$ that do not commute with $A$, I guess...

Comment: @Lior Hence *almost*.

Comment: Diagonalizability is invariant under similarity.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A,B\in M_n(\Bbb K)$ so that $\exists P\in GL_n(\Bbb K), A = P B P^{-1}$

$\forall \lambda \in \Bbb K, \gamma_A(\lambda)=\dim \operatorname{Ker} \left( A - \lambda I_n\right) = \dim \left\{X \in \Bbb K ^n, AX=\lambda X\right\}=\dim \left\{X \in \Bbb K ^n, P B P^{-1}X=\lambda X\right\} =\dim \left\{X \in \Bbb K ^n, B (P^{-1}X)=\lambda (P^{-1}X)\right\}=\dim \left\{X \in \Bbb K ^n, B X=\lambda X\right\}=\dim \operatorname{Ker} \left( B - \lambda I_n\right)=\gamma_B(\lambda)$

Answer (score 0):

An example to your request: I believe that 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
and 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}
$$
are similar, yet not diagonalizable.